# JavaFX: Make a button look like it's being clicked

Tags: java, button, javafx

There is a button in my application. Clicking it results in the exact same action as pressing a certain key. So I would like that if the user presses the key, the button would look like it is being clicked, i.e. turn dark for a short time and then go back to normal again. So, in my key handler I wrote:

```
myButton.fire();
```

which results in an action event being fired, but not in the button looking like it is being clicked. How can I accomplish the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `myButton.arm(...)`, and `myButton.disarm()` to "release" it.

Since you probably want it to appear pressed for a while, and then appear to be released, you'll want something along the following lines:

```
myButton.arm();
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> myButton.disarm());
pause.play();
```

and if you want to actually fire events when it's released, call `myButton.fire()` when you call `disarm()`:

```
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    myButton.disarm();
    myButton.fire();
});
```

Here's an SSCCE. If you press the "Up" key (i.e. the up cursor key), it simulates pressing the button:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PrgorammaticallyPressButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(count.asString("Count: %d"));

        Button button = new Button("Increment");
        button.setOnAction(e -> count.set(count.get()+1));



        VBox root = new VBox(5, label, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 150);

        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                button.arm();
                PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5));
                pause.setOnFinished(evt -> {
                    button.disarm();
                    button.fire();
                });
                pause.play();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an `EventHandler`:

```
EventHandler evtHandler = event -> {
  System.out.println("Execute event");
}
```

And then assign the same instance of the event handler as a handler for the button and delegate to that event from the KeyEventListener, as you probably want to distinguish what key was pressed:

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler = event -> {
        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.F) && event.isControlDown()) {
            evtHandler.handle(event);
        }
};
```

Comment: This is just another implementation of what I already have. My problem isn't: making both key and button cause the event. My problem is: implementing that if the key is pressed the button looks like it's being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button setAction,

```
logIn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            final Color startColor = Color.web("#000000");
            final Color endColor = Color.web("#FFFFFF");
            final ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty<Color>(startColor);
              final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                      new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(color, startColor)),
                      new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(color, endColor)));

              final StringBinding cssColorSpec = Bindings.createStringBinding(new Callable<String>() {
                  @Override
                  public String call() throws Exception {
                      return String.format("-fx-body-color: rgb(%d, %d, %d);", 
                              (int) (256*color.get().getRed()), 
                              (int) (256*color.get().getGreen()), 
                              (int) (256*color.get().getBlue()));
                  }
              }, color);
            logIn.styleProperty().bind(cssColorSpec);
             timeline.play();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use `myButton.doClick();`, this simulates the button being clicked as oppose to just the buttons action being fired. For javafx buttons use arm() and disarm() along with fire(). This page explains more https://community.oracle.com/thread/2564393?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I'm talking about javafx.scene.control.Button, not javax.swing.JButton.

Comment: Then you want to use arm() and disarm() along with fire() refer here https://community.oracle.com/thread/2564393?start=0&tstart=0